# Could it be the string::size_type type?

Tags: c++

What could be wrong with this  C++ code, sometimes it will run correctly but many other times it won't give me any result? I can't exactly pin point where the problem is coming from but I think there is some illegal expression that is yielding an undefined result. By the way, I'm using C4Droid on android and I think it supports virtually all C++11 features plus there is no C++11 expression in this particular code. 
Or maybe it is the compiler?

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
    const string hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF"; // possible hex digits 
    cout<< "Enter a series of numbers between 0 and 15" 
        << " separated by spaces. Hit ENTER when finished: " 
        << endl; 
    string result;        // will hold the resulting hexify'd string
    string::size_type n;  // hold numbers from the input 
    while (cin >> n) 
        if (n < hexdigits.size())    // only accept invalid input
            result += hexdigits[n];  // fetch the indicated hex digit 
    cout << "Your hex number is: " << result << endl;

}
```

Input: 11 15 7 8

Comment: No UB that I can see. Your problem is more mundane - hitting enter doesn't cause `cin >> n` to fail. It will just skip the whitespace.

Comment: Yeah, it'll only fail on EOF, i.e. by pressing Ctrl-D.

Comment: @Overv Or a non-numeric character.

Comment: Your main should return an int value.

Comment: It has been awhile, but I use to have a problem (in another environment) that the system would sometimes shut down before the last output could flush.  I think, in that system, the program exit caused the processor to hw reset.  What does your droid do upon this codes exit?

Comment: it remains on the screen until I exit manually.

Comment: and the problem persists even when I returned 0.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN it remains on the screen until I exit manually and the problem still occurs even when I returned 0.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: `main` doesn't have to explicitly return an `int` value. Reaching the closing `}` of `main` does an implicit `return 0;` in C++ (and in C as of the 1999 standard).

Comment: This testcase is incomplete. What is the input to the program?

Comment: In C++ there's no need to explicitly `return EXIT_SUCCESS` or `0` from `main()`... it's done implicitly if the code reaches the end of the function.  Anyway, T.C. has explained the cause... only EOF or text that can't be parsed into `n` (i.e. non-digits) and that is not whitespace (like a newline) will cause the input loop to break.  If you want to check for empty lines, you need to use `std::string line; while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) { std::istringstream iss(line); if (iss > n) { do {  // use n } while (iss >> n); } else break; }` (if you want to support multiple digits per line.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well assuming I entered : 11 15 7 8 on a straight line and then pressed the enter key, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Nitpicking, but `// ignore invalid input` should be changed to `// only accept valid input`. The comment is in the negative, which confuses the reader.

Comment: @NyproTheGeek: First, please update your question to show what input you provide; that information needs to be in the question itself, not in a comment. Second, if you provide valid input and then press Enter, the program is still waiting for more input. `cin >> n` skips leading whitespace and then reads an integer value. `'\n'` (the Enter key) is whitespace. You need to trigger and end-of-file condition to terminate the loop: Ctrl-D for Unix/Linux, Ctrl-Z for Windows. Or feed the input to the program from another source: `echo 11 15 7 8 | the_program`

Comment: A simple prompt inside the `while` loop would immediately narrow down the problem to a large degree. _Debugging_!

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks Keith, Ctrl+D did work after all. I guess android devices are truly linux systems at their cores.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Agreed, but "That's just Wrong." says Sheldon Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide valid input and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program is still waiting for more input.

`cin >> n` skips leading whitespace and then reads an integer value. `'\n'` (the Enter key) is whitespace. You need to trigger and end-of-file condition to terminate the loop: <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> for Unix/Linux, <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> for Windows.

Or feed the input to the program from another source:

```
echo 11 15 7 8 | the_program
```

On UNIX-like systems, if a program is reading input from the keyboard, you can trigger the end-of-file condition by typing <kbd>Ctrl.D</kbd> at the beginning of a line, or by typing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), `operator>>` behaves the following way:

> 9) Behaves as an UnformattedInputFunction. After constructing and
>   checking the sentry object, extracts all data from the input stream
>   and stores it to sb. The extraction stops if one of the following
>   conditions are met:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs (in which case the exception is caught, and only rethrown exceptions on failbit are enabled).

If [`std::skipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) is enabled, extraction will discard whitespace characters (this includes [the linefeed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace])), therefore, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will not terminate the loop like your prompt implies.

As Tony D. suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560110/could-it-be-the-stringsize-type-type#comment39915224_25560110), you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to extract up until a delimiter (by default, the linefeed). Your program might look like this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);

while (iss >> n)
{
    if (n < hexdigits.size())    // only accept valid input
        result += hexdigits[n];  // fetch the indicated hex digit 
}

std::cout << "Your hex number is: " << result << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+ D worked. I guess what I needed was an end-of-file. Though I have to press Ctrl+D two times for it to work. Don't know why.